# It's possible to use Ant Design Tour component with Ant Design Table component?

Tags: antd

I want to use https://ant.design/components/tour/ component.
But there is a question raised: it's possible to use it with Ant Design Table? (https://ant.design/components/table)

Ok, I tried to use Tour component with HTML-native table *()*, and it works. But how to use it with Ant Design Table is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make Tour component work with header of Table columns, we can go such way:

Define `ref` for a Header:

```
const someHeaderRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
```

Pass it to a Table columns definition:

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: (
      <>
        Some Header
        <span
          ref={someHeaderRef}
        />
      </>
    ),
    dataIndex: 'someHeader',
  }
];
```

Define this `ref` into Tour steps:

```
const steps: TourProps['steps'] = [
    {
      title: 'Some Header',
      description: '',
      target: someHeaderRef.current,
    },
];

<Tour steps={steps} />
```